# Passing different class objects into a function and getting it's properties in Haxe?

Tags: haxe, openfl

Passing different class objects into a function and getting it's properties ?

For example:

I have two different class objects :

```
screenA = new ScreenA();
screenB = new ScreenB();
```

I pass the objects in the tween:

```
switch (state)
{

    case States.SCREEN_A:
        {
            Actuate.tween(screenA, 0.6, {alpha: 1} ).ease(Sine.easeIn).autoVisible (true).onComplete(onComp, [screenA]);
        }
    case States.SCREEN_B:
        {
            Actuate.tween(screenB, 0.6, {alpha: 1} ).ease(Sine.easeIn).autoVisible (true).onComplete(onComp, [screenB]);
        }
}
```

Now i want to access a method of the passed object here, when tween completes.

Tween is passing the object but i am unable to cast it in the function to get the object methods.

```
private function onComp(screen:?)
{
    screen.load();
}
```

And compiler is always asking for the type. I have tried `Dynamic` / `Any` but then it says "load method not found", If i pass the object without any type arguments in the function then it is getting it as an object but not the class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a lot of ways you could do this, but one is with a common interface:

```
class ScreenA implements OnTweenComplete { ... }
class ScreenB implements OnTweenComplete { ... }

interface OnTweenComplete {
  public function on_tween_complete();
}
```

Then your function is:

```
private function onComp(screen:OnTweenComplete)
{
    screen.on_tween_complete();
}
```

Or perhaps, type-check it with `Std.is` and cast it:

```
private function onComp(screen:Dynamic)
{
    if (Std.is(screen, OnTweenComplete)) {
      (cast screen).on_tween_complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: i was used to pass objects into the functions directly in action script this pretty much clear my concepts about using interfaces. (y)

Answer (score 0):

In this exact example, you can use `load` in the `onComplete` callback to simplify your code:

```
Actuate.tween (screenA, 0.6, { alpha: 1 }).ease (Sine.easeIn).onComplete (screenA.load);
```